# How to remove More Choices option block from checkout cart page?

Tags: magento2, cart, shopping-cart, cross-sells

Noted that sometimes More Choices block is displayed below update cart button. Also I debugged and found that these are cross sell products of some item which are in the cart. How to remove this cross sell / More Choices block from checkout cart page?

Answer (score 3):

We need to add following in checkout_cart_index.xml which is found at

> app/design/frontend/Custom/Theme/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.crosssell" remove="true"/>
```